# on does ot handle event like live in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a page that at run time I add some control based on situations.

I write this code for `mouseover` event for `TDs` in my table:

```
$(".TableEntry .EntryCell").live("mouseover", function () {
var parent = $(this).parent();
parent.css("background-color", "C4F7C3");
});
```

and it works fine.but according to jQuery doc:

> the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

I use `on` or `delegate` like this code but it does not works:

```
$(".TableEntry .EntryCell").on("mouseover", function () {
var parent = $(this).parent();
parent.css("background-color", "C4F7C3");
});
```

how I can add event handler dynamically using `on` or `delegate`?

Comment: Seems to be working using `on`, which version of `jQuery` are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an invalid named variable `par` should be `parent`..

You need to find a persisted parent that you will bind the event handler to ..

to  simulate `.live`, you will need to add it to the `$('body')` so

```
$("body").on("mouseover", '.TableEntry .EntryCell', function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.css("background-color", "C4F7C3");
});
```

To use it as `delegate` you need to find a common persisted parent and bind to it..

```
$("_persisted_parent_id_tag_etc_").on("mouseover", '.TableEntry .EntryCell', function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.css("background-color", "C4F7C3");
});
```

---

So you bind to the element in the `$('...')` and the handler applies to the selector you pass as the second parameter (*if you do pass one*)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put a `#` in front of your colour value like this: `#C4F7C3` otherwise you will not see any result from the mouseover.